# how to apply the style in all class?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to apply the styles in specified class even it contain some numeric or string values together attribute, but the style doesn't apply, I don't know where I made a mistake, below I have placed my code for your kind reference.

**HTML**

```
 <p class="test">Some text contains....</p>
 <p class="test2">Some text contains....</p>
 <p class="test4">Some text contains....</p>
 <p class="testa">Some text contains....</p>
 <p class="test1">Some text contains....</p>
```

**Css:**

```
 p.test*
 {
 color: blue;
 font-size:150%;
 }
```

Please advise me how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: you could just use the paragraph: `p{color: blue;}`

Comment: I want to change all .test class even together numeric or string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use in your css:

```
p[class^="test"]{
 color: blue;
 font-size:150%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Way

```
p[class^="test"]{
 color: blue;
 font-size:150%;
}
```

Demo Link https://jsfiddle.net/cne9gebf/

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>red font color 1</p>
<p>red font color 2</p>
<p>red font color 3</p>
<p>red font color 4</p>
<p>red font color 5</p>
<p>red font color 6</p>

<style>
p{
color:red;
 } 
</style>
```

Now this will work simple

Comment: i have rectified the problem now run code again it will work simple

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links which should help you how you can apply the css-attribute-selectors in variety of cases *(including the scenario you mentioned in your question)*

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/attribute-selector-css-selector/

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css3-attribute-selectors/

Coming down to your case it should be as simple as below:

```
p[class^="test"]{
 color: blue;
 font-size:150%;
}
```

Here you are doing nothing but applying the styles to all `p` elements who satisfy the following rules

1. have the `class` attributes
2. The value for the `class` attribute begins with pattern "test".

Answer (score 0):

Use the same class in all your p elements

HTML

```
<p class="test">Some text contains....</p>
<p class="test">Some text contains....</p>
<p class="test">Some text contains....</p>
<p class="test">Some text contains....</p>
<p class="test">Some text contains....</p>
```

CSS

```
.test {
    color: blue;
    font-size:150%;
}
```